# RabbitMq Consumer not processing messages

Tags: rabbitmq

I have made a consumer for RabbitMQ as a console application written in C#.NET. It is programmed to listen to a queue perpetually and whenever it find a message in the queue, it processes it. The consumer processes on an average 35 messages / second. The consumers are scheduled to run at system startup in the task scheduler. The consumers run fine for 3 - 4 days. But then, they keep on running but don't process any messages although the queue has messages in it. When the consumer is stopped and again started, it again starts processing the messages properly. But, by the time you manually restart, millions of messages get queued. Can someone please help me explain this abnormal behavior. I have other queues too which are running since months together without ceasing to stop.

Requesting prompt response. Thanks in advance to the experts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest you to look at the consumer code, it might be running but stuck in RabbitMQ exceptions. It sounds odd that it runs fine for 3-4 days.

I had similar problem of consumer not consuming messages in the queue because I was using "RabbitMQ.Client.QueueingBasicConsumer" to dequeue the message and when the queue was closed  abruptly although consumer was running but it was in System.IO.EndOfStreamException. I am using "RabbitMQ.Client.Events.EventingBasicConsumer" which has helped me to solve the issue.

Comment: I am using RabbitMQ.Client.Events.QueueingBasicConsumer to dequeue the message. Hence, probably I am facing same problem. Can you please give the sample code on how did you dequeue the message using RabbitMQ.Client.Events.EventingBasicConsumer.

Comment: @ShikharMaheshwari In case you didn't find it or someone else needs it.
var consumer = new EventingBasicConsumer(channel);
                    consumer.Received += (model, ea) =>
                    {
 //get message and do work 
var body = ea.Body;
var bodyStr = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(body);
 };